# technology-savvy or technologically savvy?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is better?

1. *We are living in a **technology-savvy** world.*
2. *We are living in a **technologically savvy** world.*

Comment: [*tech-savvy*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tech-savvy) is used most often.

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first, technology-savvy, indicates a population that is knowledgeable about the tech we have - we know how to navigate it, how to operate it, etc.  It would be translatable as savvy *about* technology - the tech that already exists, and we know the tricks and tips for.

The second seems to indicate the population is technologically *minded*, that is, will go looking for (and developing) technology to solve problems with.  This would mean our savviness is technological in nature, that we will tend to find solutions in that way instead of leaning on other kinds of knowledge.

For most applications, the two are fairly interchangeable.  It seems to me if one really thinks hard about the choice, the former might seem a little more limited, and the latter a touch more flexible - the difference between knowing details of the tech we have and developing tech, so to speak.  But, we can use either to say we tend to be clever about technology, both how we use it and what we can do with it.

Honestly though, @NagarajanShanmuganathan is right - "tech savvy" would probably be more common than either usage.  "savvy" is a short word, often used informally or casually - tech is equally short and casual, and the phrase rolls of the tongue better in a way that implies *ease*.  It also neatly sidesteps the question of how exactly to phrase the term, since "tech" can be a shortened form of either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both previous posts but would add that the description of an individual person would be more likely to be technologically savvy rather than technology savvy.

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain what makes you think so with valid reasons.